# How to prove that for a sheaf functor F, F(empty set) = terminal object?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

The empty set is covered by an empty family of sets. Therefore any two sections of F(empty set) are vacuously equal, so the F(empty set) can be at most a singleton. Now, why does this mean that it is in fact the terminal object, as Vakil claims in his Algebraic geometry notes? In Sets, this is true, but why in general? In particular, what happens if we are talking about a sheaf of rings with unity. Then I think that we actually have a problem because rings with unity have at least two elements.

Comment: Rings with unity can have one element if $1 = 0$. Never forget trivial cases :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For any index set $I$ we can consider the covering of $U=\emptyset$ by the sets $U_i=\emptyset$ for $i\in I$. This gives us that $F(U)$ in
$$ \tag1F(U)\to\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i){{{} \atop \longrightarrow}\atop{\longrightarrow \atop {}}} \prod_{i,j\in I}F(U_i\cap U_j)$$
is an equalizer. For $U=\emptyset$ we may in fact pick $I=\emptyset$ and this still works. But the empty product of whatever is terminal, so $(1)$ becomes
$$ F(\emptyset)\to T{{{} \atop \longrightarrow}\atop{\longrightarrow \atop {}}}T$$
where $T$ is terminal and the two arrows on the right are $\operatorname{id}_T$.
The equalizer condition says that for any object $X$ together with a morphism $X\to T$ such that in $X\to T{{{} \atop \longrightarrow}\atop{\longrightarrow \atop {}}}T$ both paths to the right $T$ give the same morphism, there exists a unique morphism $X\to F(\emptyset)$  that makes
$$\tag2 \begin{matrix}F(\emptyset)&\longrightarrow&T\\\uparrow&\nearrow\\X\end{matrix}$$
commute. But the condition about the morphism $X\to T$ is not really a condition: There exists a unique morphism from $X$ to $T$ any way and the equality of the two paths is always given (again by uniqueness of morphism to $T$). On the other hand, *any* morphism $X\to F(\emptyset)$ make $(2)$ commutative. Therefore $F(\emptyset)$ is simply an object such for any $X$ there exists a unique morphism $X\to F(\emptyset)$. - In other words, $F(\emptyset)$ is terminal.

Now that $(1)$ can be used to define the notion of sheaf only for a category with products *including* the empty product, hence also having terminal objects. The category **Ring** of rings with unity has products only for the nonempty case, so $(1)$ does not apply. More precisely, we can use $(1)$ for **Ring** valued sheaves only if $I\ne \emptyset$. Still, the formulation of locality with sections also postulates that $F(\emptyset)$ has only one element, which is impossible. Everything makes sense again if we augment **Ring** by adding the zero ring artificially as terminal object.

Comment: Why do you think that $\textbf{Ring}$ has no terminal object? The zero ring is terminal (and it has a unit, $0=1$). It is *not* artificial to add the zero ring to $\textbf{Ring} \setminus \{0\}$ (which you call $\textbf{Ring}$), but rather to define rings (with unit or not, doesn't matter) to be non-trivial (unfortunately several authors and lecturers do this!). Because then in almost every construction in ring theory you have to make case distinctions ... The work on universal algebra is 100 years old, still neglected ...

Comment: Actually you prove it yourself (sheaves on empty set) that only considering non-trivial rings is artificial and causes case distinctions ....

Comment: Hagen, I wanted to thank you before for your awesome answer, but since they discourage it here I remained silent. But I just found a minor typo in your answer that I could not correct myself (because it is shorter than 6 characters) and will vindicate this post. It should read "The equalizer condition says that for any object X together with a morphism X to T" and not "O to T".

Answer (score 11):

If $F$ is a sheaf valued in a category $C$ with terminal object $t$, then the empty covering of $\emptyset$ shows that $F(\emptyset) \to t \rightrightarrows t$ is an equalizer. Since $t$ is terminal, the two morphisms $t \rightrightarrows t$ agree, hence $F(\emptyset) \to t$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Does this work in any category?

Comment: Do you mean if we don't need the existence of a terminal object? How do you want to formulate the sheaf axiom without products?

Comment: No I didn't mean that. I can see this for concrete categories with terminal object in which bijective morphisms are isomorphism. Can you explain your answer a bit further?

Comment: I don't know what I should explain more since every step is explained + trivial.

Comment: I learned sheaf axioms by sections which are elements. I guess you are using a generalized definition of sheaf possibly for nonconcrete categories? I apologize for commenting many times. I think I get what you are talking about.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Hi. I can't understand how can we justify the equalizer condition. And also the existence of the empty product. I hope to ask aren't there some practical and axiomatic explanations? Although it's 2021 now but I hope you can see my comment.