# Open covering of the empty set

Tags: general-topology

I red here and there that the only open covering of the empty set is the covering with no sets.

Why the covering with only the empty set (then with one element) does not fit?

Answer (score 1):

hm, that essentially depends on how you define an open cover of a subset of a topological space $X$. Many authors define it like this:

For $Y\subset X$, the collection of open subsets $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $X$ is called an open cover of $Y$ if $Y\subset \bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$.

With this definition any collection of open subsets will be a cover. However some authors ask for $Y = \bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ instead of subset. In which case only open cover of empty set is the empty set.

Comment: I have never seen an open cover defined so that equality is required.

Comment: I don't have a reference of the top of my head, but I certainly remember such definitions.

Comment: @ugur If so, what about this question? It seems to me to contradict both your options http://math.stackexchange.com/q/538395/286856

Comment: A context when an open cover of $Y$ requires equality is the context in which $Y=X$. This is the context, for instance, when compactness of an abstract topological space is first presented.

Comment: @ImreMezo I don't see why it contradicts both my options. Empty set is always covered with an empty family as there is nothing to cover! This is true in both of the contexts I suggested.

Comment: @ugur Ok. The fact is that the last sentence of your answer was ambiguous to me. Anyway my question keeps to be without an answer: why the family with just the empty set does not cover the empty set?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer does not address the question asked.

If you regard $\varnothing$ as a topological space, and look for its coverings by open subsets, then these are exactly two: the cover with only one subset $\mathcal{F}= \{\varnothing \}$ and the empty cover $\mathcal{F}= \varnothing$.

So people saying that the only cover is the empty one are plainly wrong.