# Some question on the answers (in a previous mathstackexchange page) on why the data of the sheaf on the empty set must be terminal

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology

I'm recently reading on the arguments that for the category of left $G$-sets with the canonical topology. The sheaves are all representable.

To understand the proof, I needed the fact that for any sheaf, if we evaluate it on the empty set, then it must yield the terminal object.

The previous page [How to prove that for a sheaf functor F, F(empty set) = terminal object?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538395/how-to-prove-that-for-a-sheaf-functor-f-fempty-set-terminal-object/538732#comment8745282_538732) was really helpful but I couldn't justify some points by myself.

I think I can accept the existence of the product over empty set.

But I don't know how to justify the existence of **two** morphisms for **the equalizer condition** of the definition of the sheaf.

Of course, to understand it, I guess we can just use the **the vacuousness** of the existence of pair of indices of the empty index set.

But I think we must be able to describe the sheaf condition more **categorically**.

For example, we may bypass the existence of a pair of elements of the index set since that is vacuously true. But the two maps in the sheaf conditions are induced by **the projections of the fiber product**.

Does vacuous pair of indices also gives us their fiber product?

What I want is a nice and practical and axiomatic approach(new definition that is just consistent) that can 'just' (practically or axiomatically)
**embrace** the empty index sets. (the empty covering)

So to summarize I don't know how to justify the existence of two morphisms.

Thank you for reading this question!

Comment: Please use [text formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to format text instead of MathJax.

Comment: I've read your question, looked at the linked answer and your comments on it. I don't understand your question at all. What do you believe the current statement of the sheaf condition is, and why do you think it wouldn't work for the empty cover?

Comment: Also, the two morphisms in the sheaf condition always exist for any cover, so I'm not sure why you think they wouldn't when the cover is empty.