# Definition of support of sheaf of sets in Vakil’s the rising sea

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In Vakil’s [the Rising sea, Fundamental of Algebraic Geometry,
August 29, 2022 version](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGaug2922publici.pdf), Section 2.7, in page 94, I saw a definition for **the support of a sheaf of sets**

> Define the support of a sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ of sets, denoted Supp $\mathscr{G}$, as the locus where the stalks are nonzero:
> $\operatorname{Supp} \mathscr{G}:=\left\{p \in X:\left|\mathscr{G}_p\right| \neq 0\right\}$.
> Equivalently, $\operatorname{Supp} \mathscr{G}$ is the union of supports of sections over all open sets.

I am quite confused with this definition and also its equivalent statement. Since $\mathscr{G}$ is a sheaf of sets, so is $\mathscr{G}_p$ for $p \in X$. Then $|\mathscr{G}_p|=0$ means it’s an empty set. Then it means for any point $p$ not in $\operatorname{Supp} \mathscr{G}$ and any open set $U$ contained $p$, $\mathscr{G}(U)$ should be empty set. Such an condition seems weird to me, I cannot even figure out an example such that $\operatorname{Supp} \mathscr{G} \ne X$ for some sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ of sets.

And the equivalent statement seems confused too. Vakil defines support of a section only for sheaf of abelian groups, or other “abelian group”-liked objects containing an $0$:

> **2.7.6.** *Definition*. Suppose $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf (or indeed separated presheaf) of abelian groups on $X$, and $s$ is a global section of $\mathscr{F}$. Define the support of the section $s$, denoted $\operatorname{Supp} s$, to be the set of points $p$ of $X$ where $s$ has a nonzero germ:
>
> $\operatorname{Supp} s :=\left\{p \in X: s_p \neq 0 \text{ in } \mathscr{F}_p\right\}$

With this definition only for sheaf of abelian groups, how can “$\operatorname{Supp} \mathscr{G}$ is the union of supports of sections over all open sets.” holds?

How can I interpret the definition of the support of sheaf of sets and its equivalent statement? Is it some kind of mistake here? Should the definition also be in the context of sheaf of abelian groups and $|\mathscr{G}_p| \neq 0$ be changed to $\mathscr{G}_p \neq \{0\}$? In such a modification it seems consistent  with the equivalent statement.

Thanks for everyone’s help.

Comment: I don't know what Vakil means by "stalks are nonzero" in a sheaf of sets. An arbitrary set doesn't  even have a designated element called "zero". I think we should work in the category of pointed sets instead of the category of sets.

Comment: @DavidLui Yeah.. The situation for a sheaf of sets seems kind of awkard. There are even a different definition in an early version of Vakil's note (see the link in the comment in KReiser's answer I replied to Yuan). Anyway, as KReiser said in the comment of his answer, he has never worked with sheaves of sets in real life. So I am keeping the definition for the support of sheaf only for abelian groups or rings or modules, in such a compromise all things seem fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following claim in your post is not correct:

> Then it means for any point $p$ not in Supp $\mathscr{G}$ and any open set $U$ contained $p$, $\mathscr{G}(U)$ should be empty set.

There needs to be a cofinal system of open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ where $\mathscr{G}(U)=\varnothing$ in order for $\mathscr{G}_p=\varnothing$, but there's no reason for this to be true for **all** open neighborhoods of $p$. For instance, consider a discrete two point space $\{p,q\}$ and the sheaf of sets $\mathscr{G}$ given by assigning $\mathscr{G}(\{p\})=\varnothing$ and $\mathscr{G}(\{q\})=\{1\}$. Then $\mathscr{G}(\{p,q\})=\{1\}\neq\varnothing$.

---

To see how the support of a sheaf of abelian groups is the union of the support of the sections, note that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups, then $\mathcal{F}_p\neq 0$ implies there's some element $s_p\in\mathcal{F}_p$ which is not zero. Now lift $s_p$ to a local section $s\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ for some open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ by the definition of stalks. Therefore $\operatorname{Supp}\mathcal{F} \subset \bigcup_{\text{all sections } s} \operatorname{Supp}(s)$. To show the reverse inclusion, if $p$ is a point in the support of a section $s\in\mathcal{F}(U)$, then $s_p\neq 0$ in $\mathcal{F}_p$, so $\mathcal{F}_p\neq 0$.

Finally, you're correct that the definition in the case of sheaves of abelian groups should be that $p$ is in the support iff $\mathscr{G}_p$ is not the zero group.

Comment: A uniform definition of support for $C$-valued sheaves for $C$ a reasonably well-behaved category is that we want the locus where the stalks are not isomorphic to the initial object. This reproduces the expected definition for both sets and abelian groups, but the forgetful functor $\text{Ab} \to \text{Set}$ does not preserve initial objects.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that's a good way to phrase it, thanks for the addition.

Comment: Wait, no, I don't like this definition anymore. The support should have the property that the support of a skyscraper sheaf at $x \in X$ is $ \{ x \}$, right? But the skyscraper sheaf (in sets) takes value the *terminal* object at points $\neq x$. That's unpleasant.

Comment: Wouldn't a skyscraper sheaf of sets have value $\varnothing$ (the initial object) on opens not including $x$? (Honestly, I think this solution may be either not thinking about sheaves of sets or not trying to get one definition to do everything.)

Comment: I only pretend to know things about sheaf theory but let me try to explicitly work through the definitions here: a sheaf is supposed to send some colimits to limits, so in particular it sends the empty set to the *terminal* object. The pushforward of a constant sheaf along the inclusion $x \to X$ assigns to any open $U$ not containing $x$ whatever value the constant sheaf assigns to the empty subset of $\{ x \}$. So that should be the terminal object, yes?

Comment: [Yes, that's right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538395/how-to-prove-that-for-a-sheaf-functor-f-fempty-set-terminal-object). Honestly, I don't think I've ever worked with sheaves of sets in real life, so I will probably resolve this issue by leaving them by the side of the road again.

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yeah… I checked [an early version](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) of Vakil’s notes (in page 94 too). That definition uses terminal object.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks! I am kind of ignoring it for the case of sets too. Using abelian groups is easier for me.